# Gradle test depend on class in a dependency's dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have several sub-projects in my root directory:

- special_tests

  - src/test/...
  - build.gradle
- libraries

  - libraryA

    - src/...
    - build.Gradle
  - shared

    - src/...
    - build.Gradle
- settings.gradle

special_tests depends on libraryA, library A depends on shared.

In settings.gradle, I have

```
...
include 'libraries:libraryA'
include 'libraries:shared'
include 'special_tests'
...
```

In libraryA's build.gradle, I have

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':libraries:libraryShared')
...
```

In special_tests' build.gradle, I have

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation project(':libraries:libraryA')
...
```

I am able to build both libraryA and shared on their own fine. However when I run `gradle build` in the special_tests folder, it complains it can't find symbol of classes in shared, but is able to find classes in libraryA. Any suggestions what I did wrong?